# Trouble with filenames that start with #

Tags: jquery, twitch, mirc

I am trying to use Chatty software for Twitch in order to retrieve the chatlog, but it saves it chatlog with a filename starting with # and I am not able to change that. Consequently, instead of the file the $.get returns the document itself i.e. the page that I am calling it on.

```
   $.get('#chatlog.log', function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })
```

Are there any viable workarounds for this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: did you try `$.get('%23chatlog.log', .... ` ?

Comment: haha, no I did not - thank you :)

Comment: tell as, did it work? do I set an answer?

Comment: yes, it did :) please do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
$.get('%23chatlog.log', function(data){
     console.log(data);
 })
```

`%23` encodes the hash sign as valid part of the name. In other case `#` is understud as a separator (fragment) in the url